# Evento para eliminar contenido de arrays

Tags: javascript

ando buscando la forma de poder crear un boton que pueda eliminar el contenido de un array que se va llenando con DOM, aún no pude hacerlo, podrian asesorarme en que estoy haciendo mal? Como sería la forma correcta de hacer funcionar el boton para vaciar el array?
HTML:

```
    <section class="historialLista">  
  <ul id="historial">
    <li class="impuestoActual"></li>
    <h3>Resultados guardados hasta el momento: </h3>
  </ul>
  <button class="borrarResultados">Limpiar resultados</button>
</section>
```

JS:

```
const historialresultados = [] // Array que se llena mediante DOM

const borrarResultados = document.querySelector('.borrarResultados');
const historialderesultados = document.getElementById('historial');

function borrar (e){
    historialresultados.splice(e, 1);
}

borrarResultados.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    borrar();
})
```

Comment: ¿No será que la constante es `historialderesultados` y en la función colocaste `historialresultados`?

Comment: Al manejador de evento `click` no le estás pasando como argumento `e`. Supongo que te dará un error de referencia. Lo mismo pasa con la llamada a `borrar`que haces dentro de dicho manejador, allí el error sería de tipo TypeError, ya que `splice` no es un método de `undefined`.

Comment: Soy bastante novato con Js.. apenas llevo un mes, podrian mostrarme un ejemplo de como quedaría de ser posible? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres vaciar totalmente el array independientemente de los elementos que haya, puedes hacer directamente con el `length`.

```js
const historialresultados = ["hola","que tal","hola2"];  // Array que se llena mediante DOM

const borrarResultados = document.querySelector('.borrarResultados');
const historialderesultados = document.getElementById('historial');

console.log(historialresultados); 

function borrar (){
    // historialresultados.splice(e, 1);
    historialresultados.length = 0; 
}

borrarResultados.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    borrar();
    console.log("arreglo borrado", historialresultados); 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="historialLista">  
        <ul id="historial">
          <li class="impuestoActual"></li>
          <h3>Resultados guardados hasta el momento: </h3>
        </ul>
        <button class="borrarResultados">Limpiar resultados</button>
      </section>
</body>

<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Lo que si debes tener en consideración es que si tienes más de 1 referencia al mismo array, usando el `length` vas a vaciar el array y todas las referencias al mismo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me funcionó :)